# issue with subdomain routing in symfony 2.3.2

Tags: symfony, routes, bundle, subdomain

So I have two sites, one at somethin.site.com, and another is routed to somethin.site.com/prefix/

I'd like to move the /prefix/ bundle to somethinelse.site.com, so I've changed my route set up a bit:

```
my_bundle:
    resource: "@myBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    host: %host%
    requirements:
        _scheme:  https
```

The problem is now when I go to either URL, somethin.site.com, or somethinelse.site.com, I receive the main site bundle, which has a prefix of '/'. Is there something I'm missing?

**EDIT**:
Interestingly, moving host and main_host params to under requirements got it to sort of work. The problem is now that it is going to the wrong subdomain. But if I switch the names or requirements, both subdomains route to the same bundle again. Is it possibly due to having multiple subdomains, IE (staging.sub1.site.com and staging.sub1.site.com)? [Pastebin of routing.yml](http://pastebin.com/9e1HYyuj)

Answer (score 0):

In routing the first match wins. So you main bundle may be imported before your specific bundle. Either move the `my_bundle` import to first or set a `host: %main_host%` to all other imports.

Comment: So I tried setting a main host for each of my other bundles, but that's not working, it's still showing my main bundle for both URLs. Any other ideas or information that would be pertinent to see?

Comment: Is it relevant at all that this is my test server, and is therefor something more like "test.something.site.com" and "test.somethinelse.site.com"